# Какие ещё существуют протоколы обмена данными поверх TCP кроме HTTP?

Tags: http, сеть, tcp, протоколы

Есть ли еще что-небудь кроме HTTP? Какие ещё существуют протоколы обмена данными поверх TCP?

Comment: Хм... Нууу, например, LDAP, POP3 и telnet.

Comment: ftp, ssh ещё, и ещё есть. Виндовые "samba" (SMB), и RDP.

Comment: А еще в мире каждый день создают несколько десятков собственных протоколов по верх tcp, использующихся в конкретных приложениях

Comment: а что используют игровые серверы?

Answer (score 2):

вот статья из wikipedia "[протоколы прикладного уровня](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F)" - smtp, pop3, telnet и т.д.

Comment: А всё остальное? Как же про протоколы "неприкладного" уровня?

Comment: протоколы выше транспортного должны использовать один из низших протоколов для передачи. может это будет tcp, может udp, а может быть какой-то другой протокол. Согласен что это может быть не только прикладной уровень. еще можно посмотреть список портов tcp/udp и протоколов привязанных к ним.